Langchain SQLDatabaseChain error due to SQL formatting
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

import google.generativeai as genai
from langchain_google_genai import GoogleGenerativeAI

# Ensure your GOOGLE_API_KEY is set in the .env file
api_key = os.getenv("GEMINI_API_KEY") 

# Use GoogleGenerativeAI instead of GooglePalm
llm = GoogleGenerativeAI(model="models/gemini-1.0-pro", 
                         google_api_key=api_key, 
                         temperature=0.1)
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(
                                      llm=llm, 
                                      db=db,
                                      verbose=True,
                                      use_query_checker=True)
result = db_chain.run("What is the min date?")

OUTPUT:

Entering new SQLDatabaseChain chain...
What is the minimum date?
SQLQuery:'''sql
SELECT MIN(date) AS min_date FROM gcs_data;
'''

Due to this ''' sql I'm getting the error from Google Big Query as:
Syntax error: Unexpected identifier ``` at [1:1]
How to solve this problem...?
I tried to find some solutions using blackbox.ai and chatgpt as well, but couldn't get the issue resolved. Can anyone help me out to remove this error.

what is the result you are getting when you run the query in gcs db?

I have solved this problem, just add "Generate SQL without pre-amble" at the end of every prompt. This will create queries without
'''sql
SELECT * FROM gcs_table
'''
Now you'll only get:
SELECT * FROM gcs_table
as an output which will easily run the query in DataBase
